# Random selection with a condition

Tags: python

I am wondering whether there is an opportunity for choosing random names with some conditions. I read about different random functions from random package, but they choose only one number randomly. I also thought about function, but did not come up with an idea on how to write it properly.
I have a table with many columns (~15) and I need to choose some random names (no exact number) with total sum less than or equal to 500. Hence, here I need to get two names AQ2 and COR and then I will extract other information from the table.

```
name sum city
AQ2 400 N
L3K 50 L
COR 100 Q
… … …
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to put a restriction on the total sum without specifying the number of values to extract randomly. I do not know how many values I need (1000, 1500, etc.), I just know that the total sum must be less or equal to some value X.

Comment: This is traditionally called "The Knapsack Problem" *"Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value, determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total value is as large as possible."* . I highly suggest looking that up for python and you may find some good solutions to the problem.

Comment: One of the bigger issues you will run into as you get deeper into solving for your particular usecase, is the number of permutations, depending on the size of your data, may be overwhelmingly huge.

Comment: Actually, *is* this the Knapsack Problem? You never said the total sum needs to be maximized, so what's stopping you from picking one element with a sum `<= 500` and calling it there?